DiagrammeR: dynamically compose diagramm specification for grViz
I want to create a flowchart like this in RMarkdown, and I'm using the DiagrammeR package.

Here’s what I tried, but I realize I don’t fully understand how the language works. Could you please help me?
I want to specifiy that the values of the n should be reactive. I should not write n1 , n2, and so on. Their values are stored inside an object (vector)
```{r}
grViz(
     "digraph my_flowchart { 
      graph[splines = ortho]
      node [fontname = Helvetica, shape = box, width = 4, height = 1]
      
        node1[label = <Data before management <br/>(n = 909)>]
        
        node2[label = <Data after management(n = 412)>]
        
        blank1[label = '', width = 0.05, height = 0.05]
        excluded1[label = < Exclusion for reason1<br/>(n = n1)>]
        excluded2[label = < Exclusion for reason2<br/>(n = n2)>]
        excluded3[label = < Exclusion for reason3<br/>(n = n3)>]
        excluded4[label = < Exclusion for reason4<br/>(n = n4)>]
        
        node1 -> blank1[dir = none];
        blank1 -> excluded1[minlen = 2];
        blank1 -> excluded2[minlen = 2];
        blank1 -> excluded3[minlen = 2];
        blank1 -> excluded4[minlen = 2];
        node1-> node2;
        { rank = same; blank1 excluded1 }

      }"
)
```


One way to substitute a placeholder in a string with the value of n1 is:
sprintf("Exclusion for reason1<br/>(n = %s)", n1)
